# Unable to respond with basic_card on Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm building an app using Api.ai with where I need to respond to an Intent named Login by a basic card. I'm trying this without webhook fulfillment. 
By Api.ai try section my query returns this:

```js
{
  "id": "bb09aa94-a2d0-48d5-8c7f-62fc688d17b1",
  "timestamp": "2017-07-06T13:19:30.776Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
"source": "agent",
"resolvedQuery": "login",
"action": "Login",
"actionIncomplete": false,
"parameters": {},
"contexts": [],
"metadata": {
  "intentId": "39842aa0-53c4-4d47-b3b7-61ba0fc6d80c",
  "webhookUsed": "false",
  "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
  "intentName": "account.login"
},
"fulfillment": {
  "speech": "You should visit http://www.curlpad.com for login.",
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": "basic_card",
      "platform": "google",
      "title": "Login to Curlpad",
      "subtitle": "",
      "formattedText": "Visit this link to login to your account",
      "image": {
        "url": "http://www.curlpad.com/favicons/apple-icon.png"
      },
      "buttons": [
        {
          "title": "Curlpad",
          "openUrlAction": {
            "url": "http://www.curlpad.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": 1,
      "platform": "telegram",
      "title": "Curlpad | Login",
      "subtitle": "Click on login button to continue",
      "imageUrl": "http://www.curlpad.com/favicons/apple-icon.png",
      "buttons": [
        {
          "text": "Login",
          "postback": "http://www.curlpad.com/"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": 0,
      "speech": "Open this url http://www.curlpad.com"
    }
  ]
},
"score": 1
  },
  "status": {
"code": 200,
"errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "7ba9cd11-239c-4467-8c3f-2d79d867ba18"
}
```

The telegram card works fine on my telegram bot, but gives an error on Actions on Google.
Here is the response on Actions Simulator:
[image: Test result in Actions Simulator]

Other query works fine on that simulator.
Can anyone help to make this work?
I've one more intent to search user which works using webhook fulfillment, there also I'm getting the same problem while returning basic_card.

Screenshots of intent response with the try on api.ai:

### [image: Default response with test]

[image: Actions response with test]

Comment: Can you share screen images for the Response section of your intent, with both the Default tab and the Actions on Google tab selected?

Comment: I would check that:
1. You are logged (try in incognito mode just to be on the safe side).
2. You enabled the action in onsole.api.ai
3. Try to check it from api.ai with 'Test'

Comment: @IdoGreen In Api.ai Test, it works perfectly. Even well on Actions Simulator for other Intents.

Comment: I added Screenshots with default & Actions response & test.

Comment: I added 'simple response' with basic_card and I'm now getting card in Actions console with one error.
`Error Type
MalformedResponse
expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].basic_card.image: 'accessibility_text' is required.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was 'basic_card' is not supported without a 'basic response', so we need to set 'basic response' first or Use response from the DEFAULT tab as the first response.

> **Basic Response is Compulsory for basic_card**

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a webhook, you need to do the following 3 steps as cycled 
in the screenshot below to enable the basic card response. If you don't see the ACTION ON GOOGLE tab, click on the + sign to add it.

[image]

If you are using webhook, below is the sample code that works for me. You can also follow the google documentation below. 
[google basic card documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card)

```html
'use strict';

const express = require('express')();
const router = require('express').Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ApiAiApp = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiApp;

express.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/json'}));

router.post('/card', (req, res) => {
 const app = new ApiAiApp({request: req, response: res});
 const WELCOME_INTENT = 'input.welcome';

 const actionMap = new Map();
 actionMap.set(WELCOME_INTENT, welcomeIntent);
 app.handleRequest(actionMap);
 
});

function welcomeIntent(app){
 app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
 // Create a basic card and add it to the rich response
 .addSimpleResponse('Math and prime numbers it is!')
  .addBasicCard(app.buildBasicCard(`42 is an even composite number. It
   is composed of three distinct prime numbers multiplied together. It
   has a total of eight divisors. 42 is an abundant number, because the
   sum of its proper divisors 54 is greater than itself. To count from
   1 to 42 would take you about twenty-one…`)
   .setTitle('Math & prime numbers')
   .addButton('Read more')
   .setImage('https://example.google.com/42.png', 'Image alternate text')
  )
 );
}

express.use('/example', router);

express.listen('8081', function () {
  console.log('Example app is running')
})
```

Comment: This intent is without webhook, so want that using api.ai directly.

Comment: I have added a new section at the top to show you how to do it without using webhook. please see my update.

Comment: I've done the same in Api.ai 
I've added more screenshots, you can check.

Comment: And I get the card if I enable 'Use default response from tab as the first response' but it gives some validation error.

Comment: Have you tested it on you phone? If it works you can ignore the error. It happens to me as well. It should be just a warning.